Tar piping creates error during run and stops
I am running a larger copy job online.
I am using tar for that piped to xargs.
My command looks like this:
tar cvf - --sort=name --ignore-failed-read -C /pathto/source . | pv | xargs -n 1 -P 32 $(tar xvf - --keep-newer-files -C /pathto/destination)

The command works and does what it should be doing.
However at times it stops with following error messeage:
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
sh: 1: xargs: Argument list too long

I suscpect this could happen when there is a change like deletion of a file in the source folder. Files are small but many.
So when this happens I can only start from the beginning which goes over all files that have been already copied which takes half a day at least.
So I wonder if there is a way to tell this command that it should go on instead of breaking.
It should simply go on with the next file.
Errors like missing or corrupted files from this run will be straightend out later.
I had added --ignore-failed-read to the command but it did not help.
Maybe I added it wrong or it does not do what I thought it would be doing.

Have you considered using rsync?

“The command works and does what it should be doing.” No, it doesn’t. You are trying to pipe binary output from tar into xargs, which expects lines of plain text to turn into argumnets, as in printf 'a\nb\n' | xargs -n 1 echo. That can’t even possibly work. (Have you ever checked the destination files for consistency?)

BTW, this is an example of the XY problem (Ask about X, not Y.) If source and destination are on different file systems, rsync -a /source/ /destination could help. (I’d go with rsync -aAXUNHS ... to preserve as much metadata as possible.) If source and destination share the same filesystem and if it’s a proper copy-on-write filesystem (as it should be), always prefer taking snapshots over massive copying. As long as source is a subvolume: btrfs subvolume snapshot /source /destination. Half a day becomes half a second. (Add -r for a read-only snapshot.)

@Andrej Podzimek I have no especial consistency check in place. I have checked if the files show up at the destination and they do and have the correct number of bytes.

@Mark Setchell and Andrej Podzimek  Thank you for suggesting Rsync. Yes I have tried it but it is very slow on copying the data. The tar command is much faster.
The data consists of thousands over thousands of small files. Rysnc need 10 times the time than the tar command for copying them.

You might consider using GNU Parallel to run multiple rsync in parallel - see https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-parallelizing-rsync

In case you are unfamiliar with GNU Parallel, the referenced command finds all the files in the current directory and below and passes as many files as possible (the -X option) to each invocation of rsync and keeps 10 rsync jobs running in parallel, starting a new one immediately each time any job finishes.

Another option you might consider is SyncThing - it runs continuously all the time keeping folders in sync across multiple machines.

@MarkSetchell I use [tag:bash] for parallelizing rsync

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub Cool, thank you for the links. I shall read them all through and see what I can learn. Thank you.

Thanks to all suggestions but I am not really looking for a different solution. Tar piping has been mentioned a lot to be fast and I agree. AFAIK it is working and the issue I have mentioned is the only issue I have with it. Sometimes it stops. It seems like that the creating tar sometimes stops probably due to an empty or corrupt file and passes nonsense or nothing to xargs and everything quits. So what I would like to see is that the command continues with the next file instead of quitting.

xargs -n 1 -P 32 is unhelpful here - the whole work is already done before by the command substitution $(…).

@t.mas I was reading this page and ran into some info. you'll find interesting.

You don't want or need the xargs program:
tar -cf - --sort=name --ignore-failed-read -C /pathto/source . |
pv |
tar -xvf - --keep-newer-files -C /pathto/destination

The first tar command writes to standard output.  That's piped through pv (pipe viewer) to the second tar command, which reads its standard input.  I've arranged that only the second tar command prints the names of the files it is processing (only the second tar command has the -v option).

While this works, you'll loose the many benefits of a FIFO.  I updated my answer with the explanation.

Just use a pipe.Same difference, without potential argument errors.
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo my_fifo
tar cvf - --sort=name --ignore-failed-read -C /pathto/source . | pv > my_fifo &
tar xvf my_fifo --keep-newer-files -C /pathto/destination --remove-files -j

exit 0

This achieves the same parallel extraction as the original command.
It can also be one line:
mkfifo my_fifo; tar cvf - --sort=name --ignore-failed-read -C /pathto/source . | pv > my_fifo & tar xvf my_fifo --keep-newer-files -C /pathto/destination --remove-files -j


Regular Pipes vs. Named Pipes
Regular pipes: Send data via anonymous communications channel, known as a "cut buffer", providing a simple way to connect the output & input of two processes.
Named pipes: Being an actual file, they allow attachments (processes, file descriptors), by providing persistence in the file system.

mkfifo (man-page excerpt):
"A FIFO special file is similar to a pipe, except that it is created in
a different way.  Instead of being an anonymous communications
channel, a FIFO special file is entered into the filesystem by calling
mkfifo().
Once you have created a FIFO special file in this way, any process can
open it for reading or writing, in the same way as an ordinary file."


Using a named pipe is not mandatory, but... a FIFO (in context of the above tar command) provides the ability for parallel processing or asynchronous execution.

If you have a large archive containing numerous files, by writing the data to a pipe, multiple instances of the tar command can read from the FIFO, simultaneously, leveraging multi-core CPU's.

If you want to start extraction before the archiving is done, a pipe enables asynchronous execution. You can start writing to the FIFO and immediately start the extraction process. Extraction can begin while you're still archiving.

A FIFO will act as a buffer between the archiving and extraction. If archiving produces data faster than the extraction process can handle, the FIFO stores the data, allowing it to catch up.


Just a few things of note you'll likely want to consider.

An emphasis on the flexibility of named pipes.
This will considerably help the OP, especially with this particular use case.By having a FIFO, you can resume if the process is interrupted.The data already written to the named pipe will remain, preserving the data.
#!/bin/bash

initial_archiving() {
    tar cvf - --sort=name --ignore-failed-read -C /pathto/source . > my_fifo &
    tar xvf my_fifo --keep-newer-files -C /pathto/destination -j
}

resume_process() {
    tar cvf - --sort=name --ignore-failed-read -C /pathto/source . --incremental /pathto/source/archive.tar >> my_fifo &
    tar xvf my_fifo --keep-newer-files -C /pathto/destination -j
}

if [[ ! -e my_fifo ]]; then
    mkfifo my_fifo
    initial_archiving && { echo "Process complete."; rm my_fifo; exit 0; }
else
    resume_process
fi

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Transfer interrupted. Resuming..."
    resume_process || echo "Resuming again..."; resume_process || echo "Failed to resume. Please re-run the script to continue."
fi

exit 1

This will resume, until it succeeds, with three tries.Restart for three more attempts.

Note: The -j was missing from the end of the tar command.  It needs it to use the parallel processing.
I still stand by everything I've said and using a FIFO is a far superior solution.  It handles all data types without worry of special characters and you don't have to worry about splitting the tar up.

There's no need for the FIFO.  Simply pipe the output of the first tar to the input of the second — optionally with pv (pipe viewer) inserted in between.

You say "multiple instances of the tar command can read from the FIFO, simultaneously, leveraging multi-core CPU's" — that is a recipe for disaster.  The output from tar is meant to be processed serially.  It won't be safe to have one tar process read a chunk from one file and another read the next chunk from the same file — one of them at least will be unsure about where to write the data.

You say "You can start writing to the FIFO and immediately start the extraction process. Extraction can begin while you're still archiving."  That applies to pipes as well as files.  The pipeline runs the processes concurrently.

You say "A FIFO will act as a buffer between the archiving and extraction. If archiving produces data faster than the extraction process can handle, the FIFO stores the data, allowing it to catch up."  This applies to pipes just as much as it does to FIFOs.

@JonathanLeffler The primary goal of the OP is parallel processing.  i.e. -P 32.  Well, using xargs with non-textual data or binary data, there is a risk of data corruption or unexpected behavior because it operates on textual input.  In such cases, a named pipe will remove data constraints and provides a way for parallelization.

If the -P 32 is to run 32 parallel tar processes, the concept is doomed to failure.  The output of tar is a single stream of data which cannot be processed sanely in parallel.

I don't think it creates additional instances of tar, I think it gives it the additional threads in equivalence to 32 processes.  But, I'm not certain of that.

I can't conceive of any good reason to use a manually-managed FIFO instead of a process substitution. (Well, portability to non-bash shells, but this question is explicitly tagged bash). <(...) will set up your FIFO, substitute in its name, and delete it when it's done... when you're on a platform that doesn't support /dev/fd or equivalent to be able to avoid any need for a named pipe at all.

@CharlesDuffy Resume capabilities?

The snapshot file used with --incremental can't be a FIFO itself (since tar needs to be able to both inspect and modify it), so I don't see why resume capabilities would work only with explicitly managed named FIFOs and not ones created via process substitution.

@CharlesDuffy As the page you linked states, "Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files." It's literally the same mechanism.

@JayCravens, I thought I was clear about that ("manually-managed" is how I distinguished explicit FIFOs); but it's the same mechanism plus automatic cleanup, plus replacement with /dev/fd to allow use of anonymous FIFOs with no TMPDIR interaction on Linux-y systems where it's available, plus very terse syntax.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
